# Can regression to the mean be corrected by linear mixed effects?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, ancova

I am wondering if regression to the mean can be corrected by using linear mixed effects models in the following case.

```r
model1 = lme(fixed = fat ~ visit  + diabetes  + 
         Sex  + age , 
         random = ~ visit| PatientID, 
         data = df, 
         control = lmeControl(opt = "optim"))
```

As visit is nested in patient ID. The model knows that visit1 from patient 1 is the baseline of visit2 from patient1.

alternatively, I am wondering if correcting the variance of visit  would help?

```r
mod2.lme <- update(model1, weights = 
        varIdent(~ 1|visit))
```

Am I right?

Comment: Regression to the mean is something observed in reality, not a flaw in statistical models. Can you explain what you want to correct?